# Change order and labels of local tasks in Drupal 9

Tags: drupal, task, drupal-9

I've got local tasks displayed as tabs on my users' profile page.
Those local tasks are added by various modules.
I need to change the order of those tabs, and change some of their labels.

I can't figure out how to do that.

I tried using the menu_tokens module to replace those tabs by a real, customizable menu, but unfortunately it's not working correctly in Drupal 9 yet and breaks the whole website. Maybe there's another way which I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Use `hook_local_tasks_alter` hook inside your custom module. I've checked and it's still valid in d9.

Inside your module_name.module file place a function named according to the convention `function module_name_local_tasks_alter(&$local_tasks) {`

Place there a breakpoint or simply var dump the local tasks, you will see, how many local tasks tab goes through this function.

In the end you will find `entity.user.canonical`, just overwrite the item `weight` in similar manner:

```
$local_tasks['entity.user.canonical']['weight'] = -3;
$local_tasks['entity.user.edit_form']['weight'] = -2;
```

Source: https://codimth.com/blog/web/drupal/how-override-local-task-drupal-8

Comment: Unfortunately, having a var_dump inside the function mymodule_local_tasks_alter() results in crashing the page. And I tried installing Devel with the Web Profiler submodule in order to get the current route on my page, but that results in the whole website being crashed.

Comment: `var_dump();die();` but anyway, try to change those values and clear the cache - should work.

Comment: Ah, actually I had quite a hard time finding the right values. In my case, it was for example:
$local_tasks['social_profile.information']['title']
Now this is indeed working, though the weight management seems a bit chaotic: I trid multiple values from -99 to +10 and such, and still some items aren't in the correct order.

Comment: seems like there's another module that is responsible for these fields. Check it's code to see how do they calculate weight

Comment: Each of these item comes from a different module, actually. But most of them aren't specifying any weight. I don't get why some of them aren't reacting the same way than others, still investigating. Thanks for your help anyway!